# Select SUM() works with PHP 7.4, but not with PHP 8.1

Tags: foreach, sum

unfortunately I can't find out why this query doesn't work with PHP 8.1:

```
<?php $kundencode=$_SESSION['kdnr']; ?>
<?php foreach($dbh->query('SELECT SUM(betrag) FROM qi_prepaid WHERE kdnr = "'.$kundencode.'"') as $row)?>
```

It works on PHP 7.4, but when switching to PHP 8.1 the site gets blank...

I believe that I have a syntax error here,- but which...?

Regards,
Thomas

Tried several changes by inserting quotation marks, with no success

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Yes, ideed... The system uses 2 different config files. And in both we found the same SQL query "$dbh = new PDO(..." Those identical queries conflicted, and caused the malfunction,